# Cell editor not exiting when row is deleted

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have a JTable with a several columns, one of which is has a custom renderer to display 3 buttons in a JPanel as well as a custom editor to allow them to be clickable.  One of the buttons sends a delete command to our server for that row id then reloads the table data from the server by clearing the data model and loading data again.  When this happens the cell with the 3 buttons continues to display (but not the rest of the row) until I click another button in another row even though the row is gone.

I've set `putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE)` but changing focus to another component does not help.

I've tried deleting the row itself before refreshing the data (even deleted all the rows) and made sure to call `fireTableRowsDeleted()`.

I've also tried calling the `cancelCellEditing()` and `stopCellEditing()` functions of the `TableCellEditor` and even manually setting the editing row/column to another cell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Ok, so I figured it out.  I ended up calling `removeEditor()` on the table and that fixed it.

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: no idea why not, what's wrong/really happends without seeing your code in http://sscce.org/ forms

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out.  I ended up calling removeEditor() on the table just before the data refresh and that fixed it.

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: dont think so (guessing involved, as you didn't show any code :-) - instead, it hacks around a misbehaviour of your editor: the editor _must_ notify its listeners that it is done with editing. One of those listners would be the code which sends the data refresh. That code must be delayed (by wrapping in invokeLater) until after the table's internal cleanup

Answer (score 1):

> I've set putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE) but changing focus to another component does not help.

That method should be invoked when you create the table, not in the actionPerformed method when you click the button.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that it is set when creating the table.